# Some questions about cuda streams

Tags: cuda, gpu

Code:

```
__global__ void K1() {
    int p=1;
    for(int i=0; i<100000; ++i)
        for(int j=0; j<100000; ++j)
            p*=(i+100)*j;
    printf("K1\n");
}
__global__ void K2() {
    printf("K2\n");
}

int main() {
    int *ptr;
    cudaStream_t s1, s2;
    cudaStreamCreate(&s1);
    cudaStreamCreate(&s2);
    K1<<<1, 1, 0, s1>>>();
    cudaHostAlloc(&ptr, 1, 0);
    K2<<<1, 1, 0, s2>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
K2
K1
```

**Questions:**

1. Is `s1` same as default stream?
2. As per this **[documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#implicit-synchronization)**,

> Two commands from different streams cannot run concurrently if any one of the following operations is issued in-between them by the host thread:
>
> - a page-locked host memory allocation,

shouldn't `K2` start after `K1` finish?

Comment: As per this: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#implicit-synchronization, bullet point 1, shouldn't K1 finish before K2 start?

Comment: I have Modified the question upon my new understandings.

Comment: If you are compiling a non-debug build, then the loops in K1 will be optimized away by the compiler. For a number of reasons, I don't think your example is valid.

Comment: @talonmies, the loops are just to simulate a case where `K1` is lengthy in terms of time.

Comment: But it won't be because the compiler will just remove them

Comment: @talonmies, I think that is subjective to `nvcc`. I have posted the actual output I got by running the program, compiled using `nvcc`.

Comment: Is there any guarantee that printf from GPU is a FIFO pipe? Did you run the profiler and observe that K1 is actually executed after K2?

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET, Obviously, K1 started before K2, but the execution of K1 was long enough that it overlaps with K2 and ended after K2 finished. 

Regarding `printf()`, GPU does manage a FIFO for that, and it gets flushed whenever at kernel launchs and blocking statements 
( [doc about `printf`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#limitations) )

Answer (score 1):

On the first point, s1 is not the default stream.

On the second point, running you code on a small system, I got the following profiler timeline.

[image]

My understanding is that there is a delay between the scheduling of a kernel launch and its actual launch. This is no surprise as launch are asynchronous with streams. As a result, the `cudaHostAlloc` occurs before any kernel launch. It occurs inbetween kernel call schedules, BUT before any kernel call.